# Unable to change UIAlertController title and message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am setting up the UIAlertController in this way:

this implementation is done in viewDidLoad -

```
  actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            actionButton1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        actionButton2 = UIAlertAction(title: "  Resend", style: .default) {
            action in
            self.resendCode()
        }

        actionButton2.setValue(UIImage(named: "MailForActionSheet"), forKey: "image")
        actionButton2.setValue(0, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")




        actionSheet.addAction(actionButton1)
        actionSheet.addAction(actionButton2)
```

I've set title and message as nil because I want no header in the action sheet.
The function resendCode tries to modify the action sheet in this way (implemented in the same viewcontroller):

```
func resendCode()
    {

        actionButton2.isEnabled = false
        actionSheet.title = "Resending Code not be done again"
        actionSheet.message = ""
    }
```

However all I see is blank title and message (header is now present). What's wrong here and how should I correct this?

Before:[image]

After:[image]

edit:
Action sheet is presented on click of a button
present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, check the edited question details.

Comment: Are you showing `actionSheet` again? and how are you presenting the action sheet for the first time?

Comment: @Carpsen90, check edited

Comment: I mean when you tap the action sheet, does it dismiss?

Comment: No @Carpsen90. Tapping outside the action sheet area dismisses and then clicking on the button again presents it.